# Как удалить элемент с определенм атрибутом?

Tags: javascript

есть элимент `<img src="/frontend/web/image/page/2016/10/avatar-podborka_vecher_01.jpg">` надо удалить именно элемент img c атрибутом `src= /frontend/web/image/page/2016/10/avatar-podborka_vecher_01.jpg yt gjlcrf;bnt rfr` 'вот так я написал код до удаления

```
function(file){
var date = new Date(); 
var path =  '/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/avatar-'+file.name;var image = getElementByTagName(img);
 if(image.getAtribute(src == 'path'){}
```

вот дальше как действовать не знаю. Знаю что удаляется так `parent.removeChild(elem)` но что вставить на место elem не знаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];
    if(img.getAttribute('src') == '/frontend/web/image/page/2016/10/avatar-podborka_vecher_01.jpg')
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно выбрать сразу этот элемент с помощью [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), и удалить его с помощью [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```
function(file){
    var date = new Date(); 
    var path =  '/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/avatar-'+file.name;
    var image = document.querySelector(`img[src="${path}"]`);
    if(image) image.remove();
}
```